# How to get the difference between 2 numbers (WooCommerce)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to create a validation rule on the WooCommerce Checkout stage which checks if the total of the order "is less" than a total allowance (A custom usermeta field) which stores an integer.

When completing the order with the following code, I am receiving an Internal Server Error - I'm unsure to what I'm doing wrong here. Basically if the total of the order, is less than the number within the Total Allowance usermeta field, I want an error to be displayed, so that the order is rejected from being processed.

Here's my attempt so far:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', 'misha_validate_allowance', 10, 2 );
 
function misha_validate_allowance( $fields, $errors){
 
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $key = 'my_monthly_allowance';
    $single = true;
    $getallowance = get_user_meta($user_id, $key, $single);
    
    
    $cart = $woocommerce->cart;
    $cart_total = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total();
   
    $totalamount = $cart_total - $getallowance;
    
    if ( $totalamount > $getallowance ){
        $errors->add( 'validation', 'You have reached your allowance. This order cannot be processed');
    }
}
```

Comment: The `$totalallowance` variable that you are comparing against in the if statement does not appear to be defined in your code.

Comment: Sorry! That has been corrected now - i've updated the code with the correct variable but I'm still getting an Internal Server Error with the code I have here for displaying the validation error on checkout. :-)